# rxDatastep - row selection

Tags: r, revolution-r

I want to select rows from `a.xdf` file based on a `categoryid` only if vector `b` has those category `ids` in it.

```
rxDataStep(inData = "a.xdf", outFile = "final.xdf",rowSelection= ?,overWrite=TRUE)
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess `..., rowSelection=categoryid %in% b, ...` though I do not have Revolution R to test it out.

Comment: I tried that and this is the error I get    Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'b' not found.

Comment: Well, is `b` defined? Is it a local variable in your R script? That doesn't appear in your sample so it's hard to tell. How many elements are in there?

Comment: Hmm. Looks like they may be executing in a different environment. what if you also pass a `transformObjects = list(b = b)` parameter to `rxDataStep`

Comment: It was a local variable in my R script. But transformObjects worked perfect. Thanks a lot!